# Ruby Money Input

Tags: ruby, currency

This question is likely an easy question to answer by referring to the [Gem Money Documentation](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money), but I've read over it multiple times and i cannot figure this out. Also i couldn't find any other answer to this question through searching.. so here goes:

This is the default:

```
money = Money.new(1000, "USD") #=> $10.00
```

This is the result i am trying to achieve:

```
money = Money.new(1000, "USD") #=> $1000.00
money = Money.new(10.53, "USD") #=> $10.53
```

Moreover:

```
money.cents     #=> 1000
```

The result of calling this method is a fixnum but i cannot add this to another Money instance

Comment: The lib uses cents for the first argument, so there isn't a way to change it. You could do something like `Money.new(10_00, 'USD')` or write a helper method/class that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @bliof for clarifying

By far the easiest way to do this is:

```
money = Money.new(input * 100, "USD")
```

I had an error in my code that made trying this solution initially impossible. Namely:

```
money = Money.new(input, "USD").cents
```